# Sending email with attachments using Mailgun and Httpclient

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient, mailgun

Trying to send an email with attachments using Mailgun and the Httpclient within a dotnet core Azure Function.

Mailguns documentation uses RestClient, which I don't want to use or introduce to a code-base and I am having a hard time getting attachments to work with HttpClient.

This question is exactly the same as mine though the answer does not seem to work with v3 of the Mailgun API. [Email Attachments in HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407791/email-attachments-in-httpclient)

The significant part of the code looks like this:

```
var formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
   
formContent.Add(new StringContent($"Testing This thing <{_settings.CurrentValue.MailgunFrom}>"), "from");
formContent.Add(new StringContent(string.Join(",", to)), "to");
formContent.Add(new StringContent(subject), "subject");
formContent.Add(new StringContent(body), "text");                    

ByteArrayContent fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(theBytes);
                    
fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
       {
          Name = "Daily report",
          FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(somelongFilepath)
       };

formContent.Add(fileContent);                    

var result = _httpClient.PostAsync($"v3/{_settings.CurrentValue.MailgunDomain}/messages", formContent).Result;
result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
```

I have tried various ContentDispositon, including `inline` and `attachment`, neither result in an email with attachments.

I do get the email, just nothing attached.

How do I send an email, using HTTPClient and have attachments included?

Comment: did you tried doing this , 
`formContent.Add(fileContent,'attachment',System.IO.Path.GetFileName(somelongFilepath));`
and deleting the part of code that change ContentDisposition
`fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition...`

Comment: Thats it!! Thank you so much friend!. If you post an answer I will happily accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the name that you are giving to the body of your files(it's not the file name or title)
As the official documentation

```
ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Name is the the name for the content body part.
```

and the doc of mailgun mention that the parameter name should be 'attachment' so you can change your code to be this

```
fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new 

    ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
           {
              Name = "attachment",
              FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(somelongFilepath)
           };
```

or to be more clear this

```
formContent.Add(fileContent, 'attachment', System.IO.Path.GetFileName(somelongFilepath));
```